# how to add two numbers on views.py in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to add two numbers on views.py, but it is not working please let me know corrections

```
new_bal = request.POST.get('wallet_bal')
old_bal = request.POST.get('old_bal')
update_bal = int(new_bal + old_bal )
wallet.balance = update_bal
```

Comment: Try this: `update_bal = int(new_bal) + int(old_bal)`

Comment: thanks for reply but doesnt work...please any other suggestion??   getting error invalid literal for int() with base 10:'400.0'

Comment: it works when i change int to float thanks once again